# how to estimate means and SD from clustered means in a study

Tags: descriptive-statistics, meta-analysis, data-preprocessing, systematic-review

for conduction of a meta-analysis I am collecting data from various studies. Unfortunately, not every author provides means for all groups, instead, means are clustered.
Say, I have independent variable 1 and 2 systematically modified in order to examine the effect on a dependent variable. To test the difference between the various levels of iV1, dV is averaged over iV2, and vice versa.

My question is: Is there a way to statistically estimate the single values for each level from the clustered values?

I attached a visualization that tries to explain my question.

Thanks in advance!

[image: example]